# Disable one option value inside select tag not working in IE6Ha

Tags: php, html, jquery, html-select

I have a select box with 4 values (a,b,c,d). I just want to disable 'c' inside the dropdown.
I used disabled property, it is working in all browsers but not in IE6.

I want to make it work on IE6. Could you give me some fix for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The disabled attribute for the option element is not supported in IE versions prior to 8.

The easiest thing to do would be to just completely remove that option from the select menu if you don't want anyone to select it. You should not be using the disabled attribute at all. It's simple: if you don't want someone to select it, don't put it in the list.

Comment: If you know the user has js enabled, or if you take the time to check first, then there is no issue.

Comment: There is no efficient way to check if the user has JavaScript enabled, there is only the noscript element that displays if they do not. Every way I've seen that 'attempts' to detect if JavaScript is enabled is not 100% efficient.

Comment: ie8 rc2 brought the support. 10 Years after it was specified in standards.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible. The work-around I've used in the past was to set the color of options that should be disabled to grey, and if one of those options were selected, I'd deselect it immediately using onchange().

Comment: I'll assume the down-vote was due to the js dependency. Sometimes that isn't an issue (private/intranet business systems). Otherwise, the user could be shown the disabled options only if js is enabled.

Comment: Javascript is the only option. +1 back to 0