# Disable / enable options on multiple selections according to their value / selected / not selected

Tags: jquery, forms

Wished result:

- 4 pulldown selection boxes, with each having same 6 choices.
- When an option is chosen, it becomes disabled on the 3 other selection pulldowns.
- Also, when an option is changed, it becomes available on the 3 other selection pulldowns.
- This same pattern has to work on all 4 selections.

The HTML:

```
<td class="formLabelHolder"><label for="field1174">Label</label></td>
<td class="formFieldHolder"><span><select name="field1" class="formSelect" id="field1">
<option selected="selected"></option>
<option>Large Format Solutions</option>
<option>Advanced Large Format Solutions</option>
<option>Scanning Solutions</option>
<option>Advanced Scanning Solutions</option>
<option>Office Imaging</option>
<option>Projectors Solutions</option>
</select>
</span></td>
```

I'm trying to solve this by using jQuery, and here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select = $('#form-221 select :selected');


$('#form-221 select').change(function() {

        var value = $(this).val();
    var index = $('#form-221 select').index(this);


        $('#form-221 select option').each(function() {

    //  $(this).removeAttr('disabled');

            if ( $(this).val() == value ) {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            }
        if ( $(this).val() == select[index] ) {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', false);
            }
            });

//  console.log($(':selected', select.parent('select')[index]).val());  

    select = $('#form-221 select :selected');

    });
});
```

I also tried this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){



$('#form-221 select').change(function() {

        var value = $(this).val();



        $('#form-221 select option').each(function() {

        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');

            if ( $(this).val() == value ) {
                    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            }

            });
    });
});
```

But it results in only following the last changed selection.

The upper code works (if you take away the first "if") half way, it disables the selections alright, but when changing a selection it doesn't enable it.

I must be doing something wrong and I'm trying to figure this out as we speak ;) If I do find the answer I'll paste it here as well :)

If someone has another way of approaching this please let me know! I'm eager to find the answer / solution :)

I found another question about something like this, but it only works for 2 selections, I tried ;)

Comment: @justkt, huh? Works just fine here :)

Comment: @Marcus - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025804/disable-one-option-value-inside-select-tag-not-working-in-ie6ha), and I know there are more.

Comment: @justkt, the top answer uses w3schools as a reference. I will let that speak for itself. As for `disabled` attribute on `option` element I will refer to the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-option-element)

Comment: @justkt, it's even [specified in the HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6). Only IE versions prior to 8 will lack support.

Comment: @Marcus - I just realized I was misremembering - it's hide that is ill-supported.

Comment: @Ulle, would you mind explaining why you chose Simons answer before mine? Merely because it was the first answer or was there something else? I'd like to know so I can improve on my technique :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Solution would be to save all selected values in an array on each change and then check for each available option if its value is stored in this array:

```
$('select').change(function() {

  var selections = [];
  $('select option:selected').each(function(){
    if($(this).val())
        selections.push($(this).val());
  })
  $('select option').each(function() {
     $(this).attr('disabled', $.inArray($(this).val(),selections)>-1 && !$(this).is(":selected"));
  });
});
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/398Sj/

Comment: The difference between this and my method is that this will also disable the option for where it's selected, which will be a problem when you submit the form.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that. I just corrected my answer to avoid that problem.

Comment: Thanks for all of ya! This helped me alot :)

Answer (score 1):

After some [fiddling on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/sSbKU/) I ended up with this:

```
var selects = $("select"),
    options = selects.find("option");

selects.change(function(){
    options.removeAttr("disabled");
    selects.each(function(){
        var idx = $(this).find("option:selected").index(),
            otherSelects = selects.not(this);
        if (idx != null) {
            otherSelects.find("option:eq("+idx+")").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

I tried with the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector as well, but didn't work as expected. The above uses indexes instead, and works as long as the options are in the same order (i.e. have the same index) within the `select` element.

I'd recommend to set a unique `value` attribute (internal id perhaps?) for each option and select based on that. Then it doesn't matter in which order they are within the `select` element.

Note that even though the `disabled` attribute for the `option` element is specified in the HTML4/5 specifications, all IE versions before 8 lack support. Reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/lhaakiqa.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help n' tips :) I will keep those in mind, promise :)